# Calculate Returns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data available with me

```
Date             Sec ID     Price   
01-Jan-2014,        1,         100     
02-Jan-2014,        1,         111    
03-Jan-2014,        1,          90     
04-Jan-2014,        1,         121     
01-Jan-2014,        2,          10      
02-Jan-2014,        2,          11      
03-Jan-2014,        2,           9     
04-Jan-2014,        2,          12
```

I am using the lag function using below query but not getting proper results

```
select sec_id,date_of_data,price,
       LAG(sec_id,1) over (order by sec_id) as prev_sec_id,
       LAG(date_of_data,1) over (order by sec_id) as prev_date,
       LAG(price,1) over (order by sec_id) as prev_price,
       price/LAG(price,1) over (order by sec_id)-1 as price_return
from   eqa.asset_mkt_price_ts
where  sec_id in (1,2);
```

and date_of_data between '01-Jan-2014' and '04-Jan-2014'

Results are as below

```
Date             Sec ID     Price    Prev Sec ID       Prev Price
01-Jan-2014,        1,         100,    NULL,             NULL
02-Jan-2014,        1,         111,       1,             100
03-Jan-2014,        1,          90,       1,             111
04-Jan-2014,        1,         121,       1,              90
01-Jan-2014,        2,          10,       1,             121 ----- Issue Case
02-Jan-2014,        2,          11,       2,             10
03-Jan-2014,        2,           9,       2,             11
04-Jan-2014,        2,          12,       2,             12
```

As seen above, results are not logical as For Sec ID: 2, Previous Price is being used of Sec ID: 1 which is not correct

Hope any expert around here can help me

Thanks
Hitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `order by sec_id` with `partition by sec_id order by date`. Using `order by sec_id` produces an analytic window of the whole input table ordered by `sec_id`, which could give unpredictable results and will always get the previous row regardless of whether a new `sec_id` group is started.

Partitioning by `sec_id` gives two analytic windows, so the `lag` function works as you would like it to:

```
select x.* 
from
(select sec_id,date_of_data,price,
       LAG(sec_id,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date) as prev_sec_id,
       LAG(date_of_data,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date) as prev_date,
       LAG(price,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date) as prev_price,
       price/LAG(price,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date)-1 as price_return
from   eqa.asset_mkt_price_ts
where  sec_id in (1,2)) x where x.price_return < 0.3;
```

Comment: Hi Mjsqu, Thanks for help, one more problem i have encountered, i want to put a "AND" condition where PRICE_RETURN > 0.3 but this is returning me error........AND PRICE_RETURN > 0.3......Can you help on this one too

Comment: That's because you'd need to use the full definition of `price_return`, e.g. `where sec_id in (1,2) and (price/LAG(price,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date)-1) > 0.3`, however I'm not sure if Oracle will allow this. Can you try it and let me know, I have an alternative.

Comment: Not working.....give me error....ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here
30483. 00000 -  "window  functions are not allowed here"
*Cause:    Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
           And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
           function.
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 16

Comment: Thought that might happen, use the edited answer instead

Comment: select x.* 
from
(select sec_id,date_of_data,price_close,
       LAG(sec_id,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date_of_data) as prev_sec_id,
       LAG(date_of_data,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date_of_data) as prev_date,
       LAG(price_close,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date_of_data) as prev_price,
       price_close/LAG(price_close,1) over (partition by sec_id order by date_of_data)-1 as price_return
from   eqa.asset_mkt_price_ts
where sec_id in (107027,42105)
and date_of_data between '20-Mar-2011' and '24-mar-2011') as x 
where x.price_return = 0;

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 58